# How to insert microsecond symbol in jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery

I have tried solution below but not solve.

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <label class="form-control-label">Link Latency:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input id="viewLink_linkLatency" class="form-control" type="text" style="width:100%;" disabled>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$("#viewLink_linkLatency").val(response.link[0].link_run_link_latency + ' &#181;s');
```

What is happen now is:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Unicode **\u00B5** for jQuery or JavaScript.

```
UNICODE = U+000B5
HEX CODE = &#xb5;
HTML CODE = &#181;
HTML ENTITY = &micro;
CSS CODE  = \00B5
```

Source:
https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/punctuation/micro-sign/

```js
$("#viewLink_linkLatency").val('Lorem ispsom' +  ' \u00B5s');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="viewLink_linkLatency" class="form-control" type="text" style="width:100%;" disabled>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just use the literal `μ`:

```js
$("#viewLink_linkLatency").val('something' + ' μs');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="viewLink_linkLatency"
       class="form-control"
       type="text"
       style="width:100%;"
       disabled />
```